# How to create custom styles for ng-select

Tags: css, angular, sass

How to reimplement css for

```
&.ng-select-focused {
    &:not(.ng-select-opened) > .ng-select-container {
        border-color: $ng-select-highlight;
        box-shadow: $ng-select-box-shadow;
    }
}
```

In official documentation said you have to add `class="custom"` and than you can implement your own styles, so I've tried this:

```
.ng-select.custom {
    &.ng-select-focused {
        &:not(.ng-select-opened) > .ng-select-container {
            border-color: red;
        }
      }
  }
```

but there is no effect. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add : `:host ::ng-deep`

Example 1 :

```
:host ::ng-deep .ng-select.custom {
    &.ng-select-focused {
        &:not(.ng-select-opened) > .ng-select-container {
            border-color: red;
        }
      }
  }
```

Example 2 :

```
.ng-select.custom ::ng-deep .ng-select-focused {
  &:not(.ng-select-opened) > .ng-select-container {
    border-color: red;
  }
 }
```

Comment: ::ng-deep is deprecated and therefore should not be used anymore. 
https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Comment: Until then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader compatibility with the tools.

Comment: Yes you are right, but i still wouldn't use it anymore. Of course it depends on your project size, but eventually you will have to refactor a lot. I prefer a global style sheet with sufficient classes to overwrite styles.